# link_to user_path(@user) not opening page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From my users index page, I want to open the user's details page (using a link_to tag) and get error message *No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]*

When I enter the url .../users/id (e.g. users/1) I do get the correct page. Tried many alternatives for the link_to tag. What should it be?

This is the associated code:

```
<ol class="list-group">
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
            <h3 class="pull-right"><small class="text-uppercase">created </small><%= user.created_at.to_time %></h3>
            <h2 class="h3"><%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %><small> <%= user.username %></small></h2>
            <%= link_to "details", user_path(@user), class: "pull-right" %>
            <h4><%= user.email %></h4>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

In my controller I have:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

And route.rb: `resources :users`

Comment: why you running extra loop, for extract single data from object.

Comment: @vipin: not sure what you mean with extra loop. Am running one loop on index page to list all users (each in list-group-item); then from individual user open user details page.

Comment: your above is show.html.erb

Comment: @vipin - it is from the index page; not the show page.

Comment: so why you show, your show.rb action

Comment: not sure where the issue was; might have been a route issue :-)

Comment: if you have any question, please show all method and view. you show only view having no name and show action. so that's why i am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have written `@user` and it is not assigned any value. As instance variables' default value is `nil`, it is just passing nil instead of raising any error.

Change

```
<%= link_to "details", user_path(@user), class: "pull-right" %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "details", user_path(user), class: "pull-right" %>
```

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
in you show action you define @user, means only single user  so there is not any loop for extract data from object.

```
<ol class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
                <h3 class="pull-right"><small class="text-uppercase">created </small><%= @user.created_at.to_time %></h3>
                <h2 class="h3"><%= @user.first_name %> <%= @user.last_name %><small> <%= @user.username %></small></h2>
                <%= link_to "details", user_path(@user), class: "pull-right" %>
                <h4><%= @user.email %></h4>
            </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Work for me too..!! thnx