# Rails: make list item clickable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Instead of the link_to tag to show details (see code below), I want to make the entire list item clickable.

```
<ol class="list-group">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <h3 class="pull-right"><small class="text-uppercase">created </small><%= user.created_at.to_time %></h3>
        <h2 class="h3"><%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %><small> <%= user.username %></small></h2>
        <%= link_to "details", user_path(@user), class: "pull-right" %>
        <h4><%= user.email %></h4>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

Have already tried with <% link_to .... |do| around the li. However that makes all the data in the li separately clickable. How can this be done?

Comment: via `jquery` you can attach a `click` listener to `<li>` tag and then you can programmatically `click` on link present within it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link\_to user\_path(@user) not opening page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139429/link-to-user-pathuser-not-opening-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using bootstrap you should look at the clickable [linked list group item](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-linked). This uses `div`s and `a` tags instead of lists. Below is how it might look:

```
<div class="list-group">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to user_path(user), class: "list-group-item" do %>
        <h3 class="pull-right"><small class="text-uppercase">created </small><%= user.created_at.to_time %></h3>
        <h2 class="h3"><%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %><small> <%= user.username %></small></h2>
        <h4><%= user.email %></h4>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: yes using bootstrap and good point; throws error "undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/users/3":String"

Comment: I had a typo in the `link_to` call - I had `@user` instead of `user`. Although, without seeing the rest of your code it's difficult to debug. Basically, the answer to your question 'how can i make list items clickable' is to use the linked list group item that I linked to.

Comment: agree; now need to figure out the bug that throws the error :-) - is on this line: <%= link_to "details", user_path(user), class: "list-group-item clearfix" do %>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986559/rails-undefined-method-stringify-keys. Remove "details" from your `link_to`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: mrwillihog - how would i achieve the same using a table? Like so does not work:
 <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>User name</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Last update</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to user_path(user) do %>
    <tr>
     <td><%= user.first_name %></td>
     <td><%= user.last_name %></td>
     <td><%= user.email %></td>
     <td><%= user.username %></td>...

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
   <%= link_to "details", user_path(user), class: "pull-right" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this kind of an approach. First I will have my path somewhere in my link, to I can make use of it via javascript "easily", like this

```
<li class="clickable-link" data-link-path="<%= user_path(@user) %>">
  ...
</li>
```

Which will look like this probably

```
<li class="clickable-link" data-link-path="/users/47">
  ...
<li>
```

Then some javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clickable-link").on('click', function(e){
    url = $(this).attr('data-link-path');
    window.location = url;
  });
});
```

Then some css

```
.clickable-link{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the route path in onclick event using window.location.href as bellow,

```
<ol class="list-group">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li class="list-group-item clearfix" onclick="window.location.href='<%=user_path(@user)%>'">
        <h3 class="pull-right"><small class="text-uppercase">created </small><%= user.created_at.to_time %></h3>
        <h2 class="h3"><%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %><small> <%= user.username %></small></h2>
        <%= link_to "details", user_path(@user), class: "pull-right" %>
        <h4><%= user.email %></h4>
    </li>
```

Then you can add style cursor pointer to 'li' tag.

Thanks.